# Performance and layout issues using ListView with DataTemplate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I’m currently making an app for iOS and Android using Xamarin Forms. The whole app is working fine except one menu which is giving me some hard time. It’s a list of pictures, shown in a card view style, with a title and a text. Nothing really crazy.
The goal is to get this (it's a screenshot from my app using random pictures) :
[image]

Doing this menu, I faced many problems. Every time I tried a new approach, I faced new problems.

**Performance :**
On iOS, my list view is fine, and never lags, even with many pictures (approximately 30 right now, but I plan to add more). But on Android, it starts to lag and the picture stop showing after I add "too many" (more than 10 is enough to have the menu completely not working). The pictures are embedded in the app, I thought maybe reducing size would help. I've made them "800" max (height or width) but that didn't help. I then thought that the layout was "too complicated". I made a test with a ListView containing only this in the data template :
`

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Fill" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Margin="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
</StackLayout>
```

`

And it still lags.. I guess that the layout is not an issue. So my question is : is really Android not capable of showing a list of 10/20 pictures side by side using a data template ?!
I've then tried using a third party (FFImageLoading). I have better results. But it's completely destroying the layout on iOS...

**Bugs**
I have many bugs (render bugs). I tried to solve all of them but still, in that screenshot above, there are already 2 I can see directly :
- Title 3 is fine, when Title 4 is few pixels above the picture when it shouldn't
- The place reserved for the description is bigger (2/3 lines) when it should be like the description of image 4

**Layout**
How I did, and 2 main ways I tried :
The current way (from the screenshot) is this :
`

```
<Frame Style="{StaticResource CardStyle}" Padding="0">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image HorizontalOptions="Fill" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Margin="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Frame HasShadow="false" Padding="0" Margin="0,-50,0,0" HeightRequest="45" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TranslucidFrameBackgroundColor}"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource LightLabelStyle}" FontSize="18" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Frame>
        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

`

I hate the "-50" margin which I had to put on the title's frame. That's why I sometimes get few pixel up or down and it's not always perfectly aligned with the photo.
I can't explain myself why the description (last label) is not always having a perfect size (or at least always the same, when the text is the same)...

Of course you will say "you should use a Grid and not a StackLayout, the render will be better, you won't need the -50, and the performance is better with Grid than StackLayout when you use images on Xamarin" (I read that everywhere in the forum at least).
Well, guess what :smiley:  that's what I did first and it was a disaster !

I give you the code I used :
`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Margin="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
    <Frame Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End" HasShadow="false" Padding="0" Margin="0" HeightRequest="45" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TranslucidFrameBackgroundColor}"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource LightLabelStyle}" FontSize="18" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Frame>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

`

I very much prefer this version of the template. It's much more clear and precise and doesn't need some weird margin to make it work.
But look at the result :
[image]

From what I understand, iOS (not Android), using Xamarin Forms at least, gets the size of the grid using the original picture, not the "resized to fit the screen" size of the picture... So my grids are huge and we don't even see the cards anymore. The gaps between 2 pictures gets bigger and bigger every time you add a picture...
I saw some tweaks about forcing resize using code behind but I really don't want to do that as I find it plain ugly.

Can anyone tell me, I'm "new" to Xamarin Forms, I come from many years developing using WPF / xaml : is there no way to do such a simple template using Xamarin Forms ? I saw maaaaany threads on the forums (here and stackoverflow) concerning this particular subject (pictures in data template). I tried many other solutions but didn't want to pollute this already huge question. I tried forcing a fixed size, but I hope you guessed it, that's not what I want to do as my pictures can be portrait or landscape, big or small..
Please don't ask me if I put "HasUnevenRows" to true (yes I did :wink: ).

Please, please, please help me :blush: Find a solution, tell me "omg you're so stupid you just forgot * add something here * and it would work" : that would make me so happy :smiley:

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is you are not giving the template a size to try and fit the images into. The layout engine has to look at all the images and try and figure out how to size each element to fit them in.

Can you give the grid or stack layout a height? Or the image? Then use aspect fill to place the images inside.

I see you tried FFImageLoading - you should always use that plugin when using images on Android otherwise you will suffer from performance and memory issues.

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't want to set a fixed size. I'm used to making interfaces which adapt to any kind of devices : smartphones, tablets, small or big Android phones etc. I'm used to WPF on Windows and it works perfectly. I'm shocked that Xamarin can't handle a simple "auto" layout...
About FFImageLoading, I'm actually using it on Android. The code shown here is for iOS. But using FFImageLoading it seems to be "blury" sometimes or having some weird behaviors like "loading/unloading" the photo when I scroll and it makes the scrolling "jumpy"...